# Get true color from photo

Tags: graphics, colors, color-detection

I have following problem. I am developing android app, that would allow you to get real color from photo that was captured by phone camera. You just pick a pixel and get a real color.
How I was trying to solve it: I captured a photo of real black and get its color in photo. Obviously it was not same every time I captured, because of light and etc. But it something close to (0, 0, 0) in RGB. Last time I got (12, 13, 45). And then I captured image where I want to get true colors and when I pick a pixel there I tried to do some vector math. I know that (0, 0, 0) was converted by camera to (12, 13, 45), and so any other color (x, y, z) should be something like (x + 12, y + 13, z + 45). But now I see that it is not right assumption.

So does anybody know how to solve this problem?

**EDIT**
Not real color. I want to get a color that is very close to the real one.

Comment: "You just pick a pixel and get a real color". What is real color according to you? More importantly how many colors do you think are real and what are their RGB Values? Because in RGB there will be 2(raiseto)24 unique real colors. But any device won't be able to present you such unique real colors due to various condition like (color profile of device, light etc). Are you trying to do consolidation of various shades of color to a particular color and then consider this particular color as real?  For example all the colors from (0,0,0) to (12,13,45) will be considered as black.

Comment: @sameerkn thank you for your comment. My goal is to get a color that is very close to the one that was picked from photo.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to test your theory would be generating a color with paint and then go into the color picker and slightly adjust the original color.
You can watch the respective RBG vector change and analyse the impact.

(I'm looking to do the same thing and I was actually gonna just add or subtract based on the white in the image but reading your question made me realise I'll have to figure it out another way)